# Efficient way to make connection to azure data factory in .Net core API app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, repository-pattern

net core application. I am trying to call azure data factory from my .net core app. To establish connection and call adf I have created below interface with two methods.

```
 public interface IAzureDataFactoryRepository
 {
    public DataFactoryManagementClient InitiateConnection(AuthenticationConfig authenticationConfig);

    public Task<string> RunADFPipeline(DataFactoryManagementClient dataFactoryManagementClient, Dictionary<string, object> keyValuePairs, string resourceGroup, string dataFactoryName, string pieplineName);
 }
```

Then I implemented in class as below.

```
 public class AzureDataFactoryRepository : IAzureDataFactoryRepository
    {  

        private DataFactoryManagementClient _dataFactoryManagementClient;

        public DataFactoryManagementClient InitiateConnection(AuthenticationConfig authenticationConfig)
        {   
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + authenticationConfig.TenantId);
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(authenticationConfig.ClientId, authenticationConfig.ClientSecret);
            AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync(
                "https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
            ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
            _dataFactoryManagementClient = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred)
            {
                SubscriptionId = authenticationConfig.SubscriptionId
            };
            return _dataFactoryManagementClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> RunADFPipeline(DataFactoryManagementClient dataFactoryManagementClient, Dictionary<string,object> keyValuePairs, string resourceGroup, string dataFactoryName, string pieplineName)
        {  
                CreateRunResponse runResponse = dataFactoryManagementClient.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pieplineName, parameters: keyValuePairs).Result.Body;
                return runResponse.RunId;
        }
    }
```

Above Interface and Class I added in Repository Layer. Whenever I want to call my ADF pipeline I am doing like below.

```
            var adfAuthSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdF").Get<ADFClient>();

            var azureAdAuthSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AuthenticationConfig>();

            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"parameter", parameters}
                };

            DataFactoryManagementClient dataFactoryManagementClient = azureDataFactoryRepository.InitiateConnection(azureAdAuthSettings);
            var result = await azureDataFactoryRepository.RunADFPipeline(dataFactoryManagementClient, parameters, adfAuthSettings.ResourceGroupName, adfAuthSettings.DataFactoryName, ApplicationConstants.SciHubPipeline);
            return result;
```

In the above code whenever I want to call ADF repository RunADFPipeline first I should always call InitiateConnection by passing values from my Configuration. Also each time I should do call `adfAuthSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdF").Get<ADFClient>();`to load values to model. Is there any way can we do it only once instead of doing inside all methods?
Then I will be able to RunADFPipeline method. Every time InitiateConnection should be called before calling RunADFPipeline. Is there any way we can write above code more efficiently? Can anyone suggest me better approach. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the model you can use :

```
  public class AuthenticationConfig : IAuthenticationConfig 
  {
    public AuthenticationConfig ()
    {
    }
    public string Config{ get; set; }           
  }

  public interface IAuthenticationConfig 
  {
     public string Config{ get; set; }
  }
```

This in startup  :

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
       Configuration = configuration;
    }  
  
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }    

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    { 
            services.Configure<AzureSettings>(options =>
            {
               options.Config= 
               Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationConfig : Config").Value;
          });
            //*inject your repositories 
            services.AddSingleton<IAzureDataFactoryRepository, AzureDataFactoryRepository >();

      }
```

By configuring this in your starup you make it possible to use it across your soulution :

```
 public class AzureDataFactoryRepository : IAzureDataFactoryRepository
 {  
    private readonly  AuthenticationConfig _authenticationConfig;
    public AzureDataFactoryRepository(IOptions<AzureSettings> authenticationConfig)
    {            
      _authenticationConfig= _authenticationConfig.Value.Config;           
    }
 //...
 }
```

Here you have another example of **Options** pattern:

[Dependency injection between two ASP.NET Core projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994950/dependency-injection-between-two-asp-net-core-projects/62995528#62995528)

You can use it to inject your settings and make them visible for entire solution. Its strongly recomennded by Microsoft.

If you want to read more :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks Mike. So I should look into IOption pattern?

Comment: Yes because when you do : GetSection("AzureAd") you get it  from your appsettings.json. By using IOptions you can get in once inject in pipline and then every time you need you can put it in constructor

Comment: I am implementing it thanks a lot. Small questions. I have done something like below in startup.cs services.Configure<AuthenticationConfig> (options => Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options)); Now If i want to use there values in startup.cs only then how can i use ?

Comment: Also If I want to use config in other project in same solution how can I do this? I can pass in parameter but then I need to make reference to model right?

Comment: Hi Mike This solution is working fine. But when I pass values to other project Its not working.  If I pass azureDataFactoryRepository.InitiateConnection(this._authenticationConfig); Then it throws Mode.get returned null. This is my declaration public AuthenticationConfig _authenticationConfig { get; set; } and in constructor I have this._authenticationConfig = authenticationConfig.Value;

Comment: Probably you need reference from your UserInterface/webService(main project, the one with appsettings) project to the project where you inject Options. If you put the model in the project where you inject options and referance from you mainproject then you are home, because you avoid circural  reference.

Comment: I updated again my answer. btw I always used it like this :  _authenticationConfig= _authenticationConfig.Value.Config based on the model you are providing